# Get the url all the filename inside the folder

Tags: jquery

I have a question about my javascript function to get the url inside the folder of the site,how to get all the file inside that folder name 'rrs'

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;<br>
  if(baseurl == window.location.origin+'/test/rrs/*') {
    alert('correct');
  }
  else {
    alert('wrong');
  }<br>
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it in the client side, you need to have a server side script(like php/java etc) to do that and return the result...

Comment: ahh,i see,Thank you,can you give me a hint for php??

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php